# How to Querying Nested Arrays in Firestore with Firebase Admin Python

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have a data structure in Firestore that contains nested arrays, as shown in the following JSON example:

```
{
    "courses": [
        {
            "name_courses": "ECONOMIC",
            "schedule": [
                {
                    "date": "22-01-2024",
                    "time": "14.00 - 15.40 ",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "name_courses": "STATISTIC",
            "schedule": [
                {
                    "date": "23-01-2024",
                    "time": "14.30 - 15.40 ",
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query Firestore to retrieve documents that have a specific date value within the nested array courses.schedule.date. For example, if I want to retrieve documents that have the date value of 23-01-2024, I want to get all documents that have an element in the courses.schedule array with the matching date value.

I am using Python with the firebase_admin module to interact with Firestore. I have tried using the array_contains and array_contains_any methods, but I have been unsuccessful in retrieving the desired documents.

I so confusing in understanding how to query nested arrays in Firestore using Firebase Admin Python. Thank you for your help and time in assisting me with this question.

Comment: This query is not possible with Firestore.  It can't match partial items in an array field.  Array type fields can only be queried for the entire contents of a single item (for you, that would require knowing both the value of date and time).  You will need to restructure your data so that the values you want to match are are not nested in an object.  Perhaps you want a top-level array field with only date strings in it, then you can use array-contains.  Or, perhaps schedule should be a subcollection of documents instead of an array